# Sort links D3js force directed graph

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I have a force directed graph, with 3 colors (red, green, and orange) for links.
is it possible to sort links according to there colors?

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: Could you add a provide a [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) sample of your current setup?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WV4fH/
thanks .

Comment: Please add your HTML markup to the sample.

Comment: it doesn't works because arrays of data are set dynamically from an odata service :(

Comment: I guess you can put some test/sample data in your jsfiddle.

Comment: Sort links you mean have the nodes connected by red links all grouped together on the graph or have a function that inputs a color and outputs the links associated to this color ?

Comment: Hi barnab
yes i have a function that inputs a color and outputs the links associated to this color 
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

d3 has a `sort` method that operates on selections. So if you're wanting to sort the selection by color, you might do it this way:

```
var order = {red: -1, green: 0, orange: 1};

var links = d3.selectAll('line.link')
  // a and b are data items, in this case links. This code assumes that there
  // exists a color property on the links which is 'red', 'green', or 'orange'.
  .sort(function(a, b) {
    return order[a.color] < order[b.color] ? -1 : order[b.color] < order[a.color] ? 1 : 0;
  });
```

It appears from the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-order) that this also sorts DOM elements so that the document order is equivalent to the selection order:

> **selection.sort(comparator)**
>
> Sorts the elements in the current selection according to the specified
>   comparator function. The comparator function is passed two data
>   elements a and b to compare, returning either a negative, positive, or
>   zero value. If negative, then a should be before b; if positive, then
>   a should be after b; otherwise, a and b are considered equal and the
>   order is arbitrary. Note that the sort is not guaranteed to be stable;
>   however, it is guaranteed to have the same behavior as your browser's
>   built-in sort method on arrays.
>
> **selection.order()**
>
> Re-inserts elements into the document such that the document order
>   matches the selection order. This is equivalent to calling sort() if
>   the data is already sorted, but much faster.

The `order` method makes DOM element order match the selection order, and is preferable if the selection is already sorted.

Documentation:

[selection.sort()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-sort)

[selection.order()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-order)